# How to integration test console application in solution?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application

I have a console app (which will later be installed as a Windows Service) that basically runs an infinite loop that reads messages from a queue and does something with that message.

I'd like to create an automated test case to launch test end-to-end behavior. My question is, what's the best way to launch the application in a unit test?
do  I use Process.Start?
or can I reference the Program.cs - static void main directly and run that?

ideas? sample code would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Update: Yes, I know this is an integration test. I've updated the title. I've already separated out my logic for the business logic. The value of integration testing is really to do this in an automated fashion. It makes sure all my config settings are correct, there my issues with assembly versions are ok, my logging is and database and queue and cache access are all running, etc.]

Comment: Ideally, you'd have a class in your Program.cs that does the work for you. So you're Program.cs would just construct and call whatever method on that class. That way if you have dependencies in your console app (like data for example) then you could inject those in your unit test.

Comment: If you're talking about **unit testing**...what about tests for each single class (strictly speaking) in your app? You shouldn't test app all together but its components. Also with corner cases your app (as black box) probably won't/shouldn't get. For integration testing then run your app with Process.Start(), calling its classes directly will break the test because your test bench will/may affect its environment too much.

Answer (score 2):

When I create this type of setup, I put all of the work in a separate DLL.  The Windows Service / Console App is in a tiny project that delegates most of the work to the DLL.  Most of the functional testing happens against that DLL.

To test the final executable, I would launch a process (presuming your test is generating messages that the console add handles in a way that your unit test can measure).

Make sure that you have an appropriate means of terminating the console app (such as sending a "shutdown" message), and check that the process actually exits in your unit test.

If you have multiple unit tests that all want to launch the console app they will not be able to run tests in parallel if each individual test starts the console app.  In that case, have your test class be responsible for starting and ending the process, rather than each individual unit test.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related [article in Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/261190/How-to-Debug-or-Test-your-Windows-Service-Without) which recommends conditional compilation for debugging:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        #if(!DEBUG)
           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
           ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
       { 
            new MyService() 
       };
           ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #else
           MyService myServ = new MyService();
           myServ.Process();
           // here Process is my Service function
           // that will run when my service onstart is call
           // you need to call your own method or function name here instead of Process();
        #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: He's (presumably) already doing that.  His question is how to test the program, not how to compile as a service vs as a console app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference the .exe and call `main` if you make it public:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Implementation here...
    }
}
```

It wouldn't be a *unit test*, though, as others have pointed out.